# location.onLocationChanged is calling even when i am not moving at all

Tags: flutter, location

Following Code shows that in a flutter widget I have used `location.onLocationChanged` listeners so that i can record some points while a person moves and later show them on the map as a path. but it is not working as soon as i come on this same page it starts to call continuously.Even when I am not moving.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    _progressHUD = new ProgressHUD(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black12,
      color: Colors.red,
      containerColor: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: 5.0,
      loading: false,
      text: 'Updating...',
    );
    setState(() {
      isEnding = false;
    });
    checkLocation();
    getCurrentRide();
    location.changeSettings(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    locationSubscription =
        location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
      // Use current location
      if (currentRideId != null && !isEnding) {
        final collRef = Firestore.instance.collection('rideLocations');
        DocumentReference docReference = collRef.document();
        docReference.setData({
          "lat": currentLocation.latitude,
          "long": currentLocation.longitude,
          "time": new DateTime.now(),
          "locationId": docReference.documentID,
          "rideId": currentRideId,
        }).then((doc) {
          Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
            print("init location timer");
            // Navigator.pop(context, true);
          });
        }).catchError((error) {
          print(error);
        });
      }
      print(
          "currentLocation is --------------- ${currentLocation.latitude}${currentLocation.longitude}");
      print("ongoing ref $currentRideId");
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: can you please tell me in details , i don't know how to do it

Comment: This "normal" behaviour and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

You have some request options for getting locations on how accurate and often they are.

`Accuracy`, `Interval`, `Distance`

But you have just only tell the library accuracy. Interval and distance are passed as their default values

```
location.changeSettings(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
```

It's required to tell those params to the library for your scenario.  Just an example,

```
location.changeSettings(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high.
    interval: 10000, 
    distanceFilter: 5
);
```

It basically means,

If 10 seconds are passed **AND*** if the phone is moved at least 5 meters, give the location.

**AND***, on Android, interval and distanceFilter are interpreted together. So, only 10 seconds or only min. 5m movement won't trigger the `onLocationChanged` method

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, even if you are not moving, there may be some drifting so location changes to a tiny bit.

Secondly, try `distinct` like:

```
ocation.onLocationChanged
.distinct()
.listen((LocationData currentLocation) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

you just put single line code
i am using this plugin
->https://pub.dev/packages/location

```
//interval add secode in milisecond and add distance
location.changeSettings(interval: 5000,distanceFilter: 5);
```